# Write each layer of a RasterBrick as a kml file

Tags: raster, r, kml, google-earth-engine

I have a RasterBrick which contains the distribution models of 7 palm Species. The RasterBrick looks like this.

[image]

What I want to do is to export each of this layers to a .kml format so I can upload them into GoogleEarth Engine.

If I try to write down each layer separately with the following code, it works perfectly:

`KML (currentStack_match$cuneata_current, filename= "J:/Natalia/x.kml")`

But when I try to do the same operation with the rasterBrick with the following code:

`KML (currentStack_match, filename= paste("J:/Natalia/",names(currentStack_match),".kml", sep=""))`

It gives me this error message:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (file.exists(kmlfile)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be     used
2: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (substring(file, 1L,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can anybody give a hand?

Comment: I can't replicate your error. I do `r1 = r2 = r3 = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4));s123 = brick(r1,r2,r3);raster::KML(s123,filename="stacks123.kml")` and it works, creating a `kmz` of the layers. Does that code work for you?

Comment: Are you trying to upload raster or vector KML formatted data to Earth Engine? Note that the recommended upload formats for Earth Engine are  GeoTIFFs for rasters and shapefiles for vectors. See:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_upload

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the layer names, get the layers, make the file name, call `raster::KML`. So I have `s123`:

```
> s123
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 3, 4, 12, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer.1, layer.2, layer.3 
min values  :       1,       1,       1 
max values  :      12,      12,      12
```

And I loop and save thus:

```
> for(layer in names(s123)){
   KML(s123[[layer]], filename=file.path(".",paste0(layer,".kml")))
 }
```

giving me three `kmz` files, one for each layer.

writing the whole brick works for me:

```
> KML(s123, "s123.kml")
```

giving a KMZ with all three layers:

```
$ unzip -v s123.kmz
Archive:  s123.kmz
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
     676  Defl:N      226  67% 2017-11-01 17:03 48e16549  s123.kml
    1156  Defl:N      185  84% 2017-11-01 17:03 30bf2065  s123_1.png
    1156  Defl:N      185  84% 2017-11-01 17:03 30bf2065  s123_2.png
    1156  Defl:N      185  84% 2017-11-01 17:03 30bf2065  s123_3.png
--------          -------  ---                            -------
    4144              781  81%                            4 files
```

Maybe you need to update `raster` to get this to work. I'm on 2.5-8.